# How to install sni-qt in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: package-management, 19.10

The package `sni-qt` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/sni-qt) got removed from Ubuntu 19.10 repositories (I need it as a dependency to install some other software).

Why did it get removed? Is there any dependency issues?

How to install it in Ubuntu 19.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the link you posted (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/sni-qt), it relied on Qt4 which is EOL & no longer supported.

The software either needed to be ported to Qt5 or removed as it cannot run in later releases.

> ```
> libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.6.1)
>        Qt 4 D-Bus module
> libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.3-1ubuntu3~)
>        Qt 4 core module
> libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.7)
>        Qt 4 GUI module
> ```

fyi: Qt 5.0 came out back in 2012

Comment: No Qt 4 libs exist in 20.04 now; the last are gone (*some still existed in 19.10*)

Comment: FYI:    The 'hope' for the program, and any others that used Qt4 libraries (or obsolete libs), is someone creates a *snap* using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS libraries (or a release where those libs exist). The resulting snap will run on any release (the libs being packaged within the snap).